# Elmah Logging from Linked Library (dll)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, dll, elmah

I have a MVC Web Application, and I have successfully configured logging for that web application. However, parts of my code are located in another project, linked as a library. Here is where my confusion begins. Somehow, for whatever reason I am not aware of, the exception from the library aren't called at all.

Here is the project structure that I have. I have a `Common` project, compiled as a library, that contains a helper method as following:

```
public static void LogError(Exception ex, string contextualMessage = null) {
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        var annotatedException = ex;
        if (ex == null)
        {
            annotatedException = new Exception(contextualMessage);
        }
        else if (contextualMessage != null)
        {
            annotatedException = new Exception(contextualMessage, ex);
        }
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(annotatedException);
        ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(annotatedException));
    }
    else
    {
        if (ex == null)
        {
            ex = new Exception(contextualMessage);
        }
        ErrorLog errorLog = ErrorLog.GetDefault(null);
        errorLog.ApplicationName = "Generic Library";
        errorLog.Log(new Error(ex));
    }
}
```

And then, I have another library, lets say `DataAbstraction`, which would have a call similar to this:

```
try {
    // do something
} catch(Exception ex) {
    CommonHelper.LogError(ex);
}
```

Now, whenever I use the helper method directly from the MVC Web Application, it gets logged successfully, however when I call it from the `DataAbstraction` project, nothing gets logged, but everything still runs normally.

I have tried to configured the `DataAbstraction` project's `app.config` to also have Elmah configuration, and also referenced Elmah dll to the project, but it still gives nothing.

Could anyone point me how to do this?